# Posting data with Strings and arrays using volley library in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-volley

Am trying to post data to an API using the volley library. Bellow is my code for posting the data

```
 Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String[][]>();

        try {
          params.put("email","info@email.com");
          params.put("password","12#qK-/08vA");
      params.put("professions",new String[1][7]);
      params.put("programs",new String[17]);

    }catch(Exception ex){

    }   

 return params;
```

The api expects the following data.

professions[industry id] with type Number[][]. Industry ID as key, Profession ID as value in array for the industry key

programs with type Number[]. Array with Program IDs.

email with type String.
password with type String.

When I run the a bove I get the following in the log

08-30 16:55:33.484 3817-11430/com.ajira.francis.utendaji_v1 D/NativeCrypto: Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5388f5c8, appData=0x5388e940
08-30 16:55:33.484 3817-11430/com.ajira.francis.utendaji_v1 D/NativeCrypto: Returned from SSL_Read() with result 86, error code 0 ssl=0x5388f5c8, appData=0x5388e940
08-30 16:55:33.497 3817-11430/com.ajira.francis.utendaji_v1 E/Volley: [119549] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://mysight.com/register/
08-30 16:55:33.498 3817-3817/com.ajira.francis.utendaji_v1 D/ERROR MESSAGE: com.android.volley.ServerError
08-30 16:55:33.843 3817-3824/com.ajira.francis.utendaji_v1 D/jdwp: processIncoming.

How do I fix this

Comment: volley has many problems. Its better to shift to okhttp

Comment: Could you please post your api, sample payload and headers if any?